# Go Test Input and Output from File

Tags: go, testing

was trying to determine if there's a way to take a given input and expected output from a file for use in go test.

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var n, m, a float64
    fmt.Scanln(&n, &m, &a)

    a_in_n_ceil := uint64(math.Ceil(n / a))

    a_in_m_ceil := uint64(math.Ceil(m / a))

    a_in_n_and_m := a_in_n_ceil * a_in_m_ceil

    fmt.Println(a_in_n_and_m)

}
```

examples:

```
6 6 4
4
```

Would it be io.readfile or something similar to grab the first line of input from the examples file and then again for the seconds line of expected output in main_test.go? Guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Use io.ReadFile .

Comment: Volker means [os.ReadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile). Note that in tests the working directory is set the directory containing the test, so relative names are relative to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use [os package](https://pkg.go.dev/os) for file read & write

To read from file : `os.ReadFile(path_to_file)`

To write file : `os.WriteFile("output.txt", data_in_byte_array, file_permission)`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)


func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func ReadFromFile(path string) []float64 {
    dat, err := os.ReadFile(path) // read file contents
    check(err)
    stringArr := strings.Split(string(dat)," ")

    var numbers []float64
    for _, arg := range stringArr {
        if n, err := strconv.ParseFloat(arg, 64); err == nil {
            numbers = append(numbers, n)
        }
    }
    return numbers // return file contents in required format (in this case []float64)
}

func WriteFile(data string) error{
    err := os.WriteFile("output.txt", []byte(data), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main(){
    var n, m, a float64
    numbers := ReadFromFile("input.txt")
    fmt.Println(numbers)
    n = numbers[0]
    m = numbers[1]
    a = numbers[2]

    a_in_n_ceil := uint64(math.Ceil(n / a))

    a_in_m_ceil := uint64(math.Ceil(m / a))

    a_in_n_and_m := a_in_n_ceil * a_in_m_ceil

    fmt.Println(a_in_n_and_m) // print to console

    err = WriteFile(fmt.Sprint(a_in_n_and_m)) // write output to a file
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error in file write : ", err)
    }
}
```

**input.txt**

```
6 6 4
```

**output.txt**

```
4
```